# How to clear "memory cache" and "disk cache" from chrome?

Tags: caching, next.js, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I'm building a NextJS application, which uses SSR. I'm soon going to host this website online, but I need to check how much bandwidth is used, by first-time users, when they load our application. I try resorting to the chrome developers tool for that but it seems that even after clearing browsing data, cache, temporary files, prefetch, and restarting the PC it does not removes the files at any cost.
[image]